# Expand inner table to fit surrounding <td>

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a table inside a `<td>` tag.

The inner table should expand its height, if the surrounding `<td>` is bigger.

the jsfiddle example works for FF (the black border has the same height as the green one), but not for IE7 (black border is too small).

Unfortunately I need nested tables (can't use floats) and need to support IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/qJTgw/3/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%; min-height: 100%">
            <table style="border: 2px solid black; height: 100%; min-height: 100%"><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 2px solid green">BIG<br>BIG<br>BIG<br>BIG</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried a jQuery solution, but it took 10 seconds to change the heights, since there are a lot of inner tables on the page. A pure CSS solution would be better.

Update: The border have colors to show what I mean. In my real problem there is a background image (dotted line) which should be as tall as the surrounding td.

Comment: Why don't you set the black border to its parent 'TD'....

Comment: I updated the question: The borders are just for this example.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps add height to `table` too:

```
<table style="height: 100%; min-height: 100%">
```

Comment: No, sorry, this does not help.